# open video using message from Firebase console

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase to make push notification to Android and now I get a message from Firebase... so I want when the message received and in message body there is a video name that is existing in my mobile device I want the video to play

Here is my main activity:

```
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        // Create channel to show notifications.
        String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
        String channelName = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_name);
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW));
    }


    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
            Object value = getIntent().getExtras().get(key);
            Log.d(TAG, "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is MyFirebaseInstanceIDService:

```
private static final String REG_TOKEN = "REG_TOKEN";

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
   String recent_token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(REG_TOKEN,recent_token);
}
```

Here is a link to my project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YuwJ1VedS_X4KjHUX8hh2Vpd5QQ06e42/view?usp=sharing